よう without particle
Why there is no に particle after よう ? What is the meaning of よう in that sentence ? Is it like « in order to » ?

折り返し電話するよう上司に伝えます


Because it can be omitted in the sense of “in order to” and when telling someone what to do with the one without it in fact being more literary. This sense is simply “[I] will tell [my] boss to call [you] back.”, as in:

“撤退するよう（に）命令された。” -> “We were ordered to retreat” [verb that conveys an order or information]
“死なないよう（に）言った。” -> “I told him not to die.”
“人は死なないよう（に）食べる。” -> “A man eats in order to not die.” [A verb that does not convey telling anyone something, in this case the action is performed in order to realize the subordinate clause.]

However, the “〜に” cannot be omitted in the sense of “like”.

“蝶のように舞い、蜂のように刺す” -> “Float like a butterfly, sting like a bee.”
“フランス語を愛するようにフランスワインも愛している” -> “I love French wine like I love the French language.”

In the last case omitting the “〜に” would imply “I love French wine in order to love the French language.” which doesn't make much sense, with “〜に” it's ambiguous in theory but this would obviously be the interpretation that makes sense.
